# count number of records that are not in the table

Tags: php, sql

I`m trying to figure out how to create sql query to DB, that will doing the next:
Count the number of domains, that exists in my PHP array, but not exist in DB table.
Table structure is:

```
id|domain
```

I have an array with the number of domains

```
$domains = ("domain1", "domain2"....);
```

Please, help me deal with this!

Thanks!!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM databasetable WHERE domain IN (<your domain array list here)` and then subtract that result from `count($domains)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOMAINS WHERE DOMAINS.DOMAIN NOT IN (" . implode(', ', $domains) . ")";
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Where's the problem?

In pseudo-code:

```
=> foreach entry in phpArray 
=> select entry from db 
=> if(result == false) counter++
```

Its general coding. Im sure you can work out this way.

Comment: Yes, it is ine of the way to solve this
But, I have a huge DB, and don't want to make query for every domain in PHP code...
I want to make one SQL query, that will do tis

Comment: Then `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db WHERE entry NOT IN (...);` is the right format. I wont edit my answer. The other guys in here already got such solutions. Check em out (Halayem Anis's answer should fit).

Comment: Yes, the solution in your comment is also right) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you count your array with:

`$counted = count($domains);`

then the query is:

`SELECT COUNT(domain) as counted_domains FROM table`

then compare the results and you get your difference :)

Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE domains NOT IN ('" . join("', '", $domains) . "')";`

Answer (score 0):

With mysql:

```
SELECT t1.domain
    FROM yourtable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourtable t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE NOT t2.domain IN ('domain1', 'domain2'...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all domains from the database
Store these in an array `$dbdomains`
do something like

```
foreach($domains as $key->$domain) {
 if in_array($domain, $dbdomains) unset $domains[$key];
}
echo count($domains);
```